# How to define output type from type nested in Sequence

Tags: swift

I want to make extension for a Directory. My structure is:

```
var points:[String:Set<Double>] = ["x":[0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0],
                                   "y":[10.0, 20.0, 30.0],
                                   z":[100.0, 200.0]]
```

I need to have all combination of `"x"`, `"y"`, `"z"`.... as a an array of flat dictionaries:

```
[["x":0.0, "y":10.0, "z":100.0],
 ["x":0.0, "y":10.0, "z":200.0],
 ["x":0.0, "y":20.0, "z":100.0],
 ["x":0.0, "y":20.0, "z":200.0],
 ["x":0.0, "y":30.0, "z":100.0],
 ["x":0.0, "y":30.0, "z":200.0],
 ["x":2.0, "y":10.0, "z":100.0],
 ["x":2.0, "y":10.0, "z":200.0],
 ["x":2.0, "y":20.0, "z":100.0],
 ["x":2.0, "y":20.0, "z":200.0],
 ["x":2.0, "y":30.0, "z":100.0],
 ["x":2.0, "y":30.0, "z":200.0],
 ....]
```

So in this particular case extension header will look like this:

```
 extension Dictionary where Value == Set<Double> {

      var explode:[[String:Double]] {
          ....
      }
 }
```

But what if I want to make it more Generic? How to declare types?

```
 extension Dictionary where Value:Sequence {

      var explode:[[String:Sequence.Element]] {
          ....
      }
 }
```

It doesn't work: `Associated type 'Element' can only be used with a concrete type or generic parameter base`. I can understand this. But how to take Element type and use it id output definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. You need to refer to `Value` (the concrete type parameter), not `Sequence` (the protocol).

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Sequence {

    var explode:[[String:Value.Element]] {
        ...
    }
}
```

That said, I'm surprised your return value can involve `String` here. I would expect it to be keyed by the same thing as your dictionary.

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Sequence {

    var explode:[[Key:Value.Element]] {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, „String” was mistake. Thank you!